# Assigning values to elements of an object with different types

Tags: typescript

I earlier had problems with this first loop because of problems iteration keys, this is now solved with the following code. The two types, PopupPopsDefined and PopupProps are the same except that PopupProps allows undefined. This fixes problems I had with keys the other element would not accept. The code I have here all runs correctly, I just want to do the last part a better way without the case statements and the hard-coded assignments.

```
mergeTool(baseConfig: PopupPropsDefined, overrides: PopupProps): PopupPropsDefined {
    const keys = Object.keys(overrides) as (keyof PopupProps)[];
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const newValue = overrides[key];
      if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined') {
        this.setPropValue(key, baseConfig, newValue);
      }
    });
    return baseConfig;
  }
```

The types are defined as:

```
export interface PopupProps {
  arrowDistance?: number;
  arrowHeight?: number;
  arrowOffset?: number;
  arrowWidth?: number;
  cornerRadius?: number;
  paddingX?: number;
  paddingY?: number;
  shiftX?: number;
  shiftY?: number;
  zIndex?: number;
  isManual?: boolean;
  isModal?: boolean;
  isTooltip?: boolean;
  logging?: boolean;
  debugMode?: boolean;
  direction?: PopupDirection;
  eventOff?: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  eventOn?: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  positioner?: string;
}

export interface PopupPropsDefined {
  arrowDistance: number;
  arrowHeight: number;
  arrowOffset: number;
  arrowWidth: number;
  cornerRadius: number;
  paddingX: number;
  paddingY: number;
  shiftX: number;
  shiftY: number;
  zIndex: number;
  isManual: boolean;
  isModal: boolean;
  isTooltip: boolean;
  logging: boolean;
  debugMode: boolean;
  direction: PopupDirection;
  eventOff: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  eventOn: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  positioner: string;
}
```

The following is the ugly code I want to do in a better way. Is there some way to detect the type of the object I'm copying a value to, so that I don't have to have switch statement like this. Its partly because it is so unmaintainable, if I add a new property I have to remember to add it here as well.

```
  setPropValue(key: string, config: PopupPropsDefined, value: number | boolean | string) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'arrowDistance':
      case 'arrowHeight':
      case 'arrowOffset':
      case 'arrowWidth':
      case 'cornerRadius':
      case 'paddingX':
      case 'paddingY':
      case 'shiftX':
      case 'shiftY':
      case 'zIndex':
        config[key] = <number>value;
        break;
      case 'isModal':
      case 'isTooltip':
      case 'logging':
      case 'debugMode':
      case 'isManual':
        config[key] = <boolean>value;
        break;
      case 'direction':
        config.direction = value as PopupDirection;
        break;
      case 'eventOff':
      case 'eventOn':
        config[key] = value as keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
        break;
      case 'positioner':
        config.positioner = <string>value;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing without having unrelated problems. That means instead of using words to describe, say, `PopupPropsDefined`, you should have it defined in the code. If it's necessary, that is; if you can simplify it further and still have the same general issue, that would be helpful. Right now it's hard to get started on this, which makes it less likely you get an answer that someone has actually tested first.

Comment: Typescript obviously understands which types are which. If any of the case statements is of the wrong type for the assignment, it then shows an error. There's got to be a way for the compiler to specify the type according to what it is.

Comment: ? Is that directed at me? I'm happy to look if you can make this a [mre]. Have you tried looking at the code in a standalone IDE? What's `PopupDirection`, an enum or something? Just trying to get to the starting line, here.

Comment: No, it's not directed at you, it's just a comment about the code,

It is intended to make sets of named mode configurations for a popup tool, so that you don't have so much clutter in the code. You can have a mode for tooltips, and another one for popups all specified in a separate PopupConfig.ts. 

You can still override something in the mode. This is the reason why the first loop assigns values to the base setting from the selected mode, then assigns the setting that were passed by the vue3 control instance

Comment: Assuming `PopupDirection` isn't anything insane, then you probably just want `setPropValue()` to be *generic* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOKbdw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I just pasted that into my code, it looks like it works so yeah this is an answer.

popupDirection is one or two letter strings that define the NEWS orientation of a tooltip, and if it centered or just aligned at top or left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your version of `setPropValue()` is that there's no guarantee that `key` and `value` have anything to do with each other; `key` can be any string at all, and `value` can be any `number | boolean | string`. Meaning you could call `setPropValue("oopsiePoopsie", 123)` or `setPropValue("arrowDistance", "whoopsieDoodle")` and the compiler would allow it.  That forces you inside the function to all kinds of checks and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to try to avoid and suppress errors.

Given that at runtime all of your code inside `setPropValue()` is just doing `config[key] = value`, we should look for a solution that contains just that line.  The way to do that is to make `setPropValue()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the type of `key`, which should be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the keys of `PopupPropsDefined`, and then the type of `value` should be the type of the property you get when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a `PopupPropsDefined` with a key of type `K`.

Like so:

```
setPropValue<K extends keyof PopupPropsDefined>(
    key: K,
    config: PopupPropsDefined,
    value: PopupPropsDefined[K]
) {
    config[key] = value; // okay
}
```

That compiles without error because the assignment `config[key] = value` has the indexed access type `PopupPropsDefined[K]` on both sides.  The type of `value` is declared to be of that type, while the type of `config[key]` is that type because you're indexing into a `PopupPropsDefined` with a key of type `K`.

And now it behaves as expected from the caller's side as well:

```
x.setPropValue("arrowDistance", config, 1); // okay
x.setPropValue("oopsiePoopsie", config, 123); // error!
// ----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"oopsiePoopsie"' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'keyof PopupPropsDefined'.
x.setPropValue("arrowDistance", config, "whoopsieDoodle");
// -----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'number'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-3406BJNBXAh7yhK9nWPiSJRaJ3mNJwFx+MJx7X8TJDMp7i9dPJFuV7M56v5guFosl0tlKuNOZWTfEAP01b8dT-A0APYJVmzgM0LQ0dwbTtSQHUkbBBC4Ux+jw0NLBlDAhGATd+AACl4dh0lYQhAyEB8DAQIwTH9QM6ioSg4DZRJimALhGNpFjfQASkE71WIDIMQ2IOZ4hqEB7CgDVTAAXigJJeAAKwZAA6FTyO4jRbXOLgRKsUxyI1L9H2EsyAG0AF0EXiFTdM0RQJR0JhyKs-lzNUgA+Aj4lCqAFKUupaAANSeMA9HUozeNM+yNWcuSwpUIVyNwPkEGAL8oti-h4qgABCVT1IAcjAEd2ODKrzNkzKWqgUobl07NhOK+K-L5PhqOAWiQHoygiri4ARJczKpBa8QpoyiwsFwMAKygKiaLosIEQwjsMm6iaAB4AGkoDkdQzlMayhVsn0-SkjjAvIxblP5dxjvIF6FPo8TmLutjpM+lqWQm367IBjj7OOxy5iar6tqEVL+UcqB1JBkrgB26QpAi5RZFRjxgFoKA8P6ciFvOLDOD0XHwoRsH-oe4M-FkTr9p9HrgHIgAicM7CjXRucob6wkoABGKaoAAeilqA4G5dg+UkVmuo5iaebeX00GAeATG1oW6ZG0WoDFgAmABmSWZbO-IMDKyRrYAWmdl3XeCgA-T2ve9n2HdlgBBYjIHZOWhVy-KoCq7nNbNHWY-1qqVFMEA4GUaizSEEB2AEPQ-bauAoG6DB2BlN1Q7avK9Cq679CExn6qoKrdOVtncAOjGeb5yNHEF4WEcobnmHj4AUDeKgPm5handdmfZ7n+e3agH3l9963A6EYO1HL8Oq9QvpE5uDxU4sjOs5zqA89wAui5LjING3yvI4qDAm6AA)

Comment: I'm not just happy to have an answer but this is explained in a way that helps me and other people understand how and why this works.

Answer (score 0):

jcalz had the right answer (and as an aside, I got this complicated rewrite working with only about four wrong lines)

```
setPropValue<K extends keyof PopupPropsDefined>(
  key: K, 
  config: PopupPropsDefined, 
  value: PopupPropsDefined[K]){

  config[key] = value;
}
```